# Redeclare a variable from a different block in a short variable declaration

Tags: scope, go

How can I redeclare a variable from a different block in a short variable declaration?

```
func f() (err os.Error) {
    proc, err := os.StartProcess(blah blah blah)
    // the new err masks the return value?
}
```

There's a [long thread](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/5f070b3c5f60dbc1) about this, and an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=377), but I'm interested in how to work around this for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go specification for [short variable declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Short_variable_declarations) is clear:

> a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were
>   originally declared in the same block
>   with the same type, and at least one
>   of the non-blank variables is new.

Therefore, in a short variable declaration, you can't redeclare variables originally declared in a different block.

Here's an example of how to get around this restriction by declaring a local variable (`e`) in the inner block and assigning it (`e`) to a variable (`err2`) declared in an outer block.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func f() (err1 os.Error, err2 os.Error) {
    fi, err1 := os.Stat("== err1 os.Error ==")
    _ = fi
    {
        fi, e := os.Stat("== e os.Error ==")
        _ = fi
        err2 = e
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    err1, err2 := f()
    fmt.Println("f() err1:", err1)
    fmt.Println("f() err2:", err2)
}
```

Output:

```
f() err1: stat == err1 os.Error ==: no such file or directory
f() err2: stat == e os.Error ==: no such file or directory
```

Here's the previous example rewritten to use explicit regular [variable declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Variable_declarations) and named [function parameters](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Function_types) rather than implicit [short variable declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Short_variable_declarations). Variable declarations can always be written explicitly as regular variable declarations or named function parameters; implicit short variable declarations are merely a shorthand for regular variable declarations.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func f() (err1 os.Error, err2 os.Error) {
    var fi *os.FileInfo
    fi, err1 = os.Stat("== err1 os.Error ==")
    _ = fi
    {
        var fi *os.FileInfo
        fi, err2 = os.Stat("== err2 os.Error ==")
        _ = fi
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    err1, err2 := f()
    fmt.Println("f() err1:", err1)
    fmt.Println("f() err2:", err2)
}
```

Output:

```
f() err1: stat == err1 os.Error ==: no such file or directory
f() err2: stat == err2 os.Error ==: no such file or directory
```

In your example, the short variable declaration of `err` redeclares the return parameter declaration of `err`; they are in the same block. Therefore, the new `err` does not mask the return parameter `err`.

Comment: So your 2 strategies are: 1) Assign to a temporary and then from there to the variable from different scope, and 2) Suck it up and do "var" variable declarations for those names that aren't yet present and then assign with "="? Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Those are the two strategies. Plus, sometimes you can use a return statement with a list of variables in the inner block e.g. `return n, err`. As you can see from reading the various threads and issues, there is no magic bullet.

Comment: Accepted answer is slightly wrong: "Therefore, in a short variable declaration, you can't redeclare variables originally declared in a different block." --- in fact, the opposite is true. Check this: https://play.golang.org/p/NCTYWEU84z - x is explicitly redeclared in the inner block. There is no difference with using `:=` or `var` in this case, both works: https://play.golang.org/p/SS8D1a4BsI ... I'm just not sure that it *should*...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bypass the scope rules of a `:=` declaration. Just be explicit using `var` and `=`.

Comment: @MattJoiner I've added an example of explicit regular variable declarations to my answer.