# 'declared and not used' because Go compiler can't consider loops?

Tags: go

Poor title, but I didn't know how else to describe it within the character limit.

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to write a little Go program that simulates a lottery draw. It draws six random numbers to be the winning set, then continually draws random arrays of random ints until you get that set again.

First I wrote a function which takes a channel and infinitely loops "add array of 6 random ints to the channel":

```
func draw(ch chan<- [6]int) {
    generator := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    for {
        ch <- [6]int{
            generator.Intn(100),
            generator.Intn(100),
            generator.Intn(100),
            generator.Intn(100),
            generator.Intn(100),
            generator.Intn(100),
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `main()` I specify two OS threads, create a channel that can hold 250 arrays of 6 ints, and start my `draw()` function in a goroutine.

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
ch := make(chan [6]int, 250)
go draw(ch)
```

Next I take a winning set (eg `[4 8 15 16 23 42]`) from the channel, then a 'current' set, meaning the most recent draw. I set my game_played counter to 1:

```
winning := <- ch
current := <- ch
games_played := 1
```

Here's the tricky bit.

In an infinite loop, I check if the current draw is equal to the winning draw. If it is, I print the number of games played, and break from the loop.

If it *isn't*, I set `current` to a new draw, and increment the counter. The loop should then run the `if winning == current...` check again over and over until there's a match.

```
for {
    if winning == current {
        fmt.Println(games_played)
        break
    } else {
        current := <- ch
        games_played += 1
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: that fourth-last line, `current := <- ch`, throws a compiler error, 'current declared and not used'. I want to say "Yeah, I *know* it's not used after that point reading downward, but it's declared inside a loop, so its value matters on the next iteration." But I can't work out how, or if I've done something stupid. I'm totally clueless about Go, obviously. But to me, thinking through it, the logic is sound. Am I messing something up?

(Note: I'm aware of the oversight that a draw of `[1 2 3]` won't be equal to `[2 3 1]`, ignoring that for now.)

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5029819/720999).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second current is in the `if` scope. Replace `current := <- ch` with `current = <- ch` (no colon). When using `:=` you define a new `current` variable in the nested scope.

```
if winning == current {
    fmt.Println(games_played)
    break
} else {
    current := <- ch
    games_played += 1
}
```

is equivalent of:

```
if winning == current {
    fmt.Println(games_played)
    break
} else {
    var current int[6] // you don't want this, as it shadows your
                       // current form the outher scope
    current = <- ch // you want only this guy
    games_played += 1
}
```